# Fortify/Laravel : 403 Invalidate Signature

Tags: laravel, authentication, fortify

I have a Laravel website and use Fortify for user email authentication. Some of my new users encounter a 403 Invalidate Signature error when they click on the verification email link from their phone (they use an iPhone). I tried to reproduce the error but couldn't. Any potential explanations / solutions please?

I tried to reproduce the error but I couldn't. The website authentification system had been running for more than 3 years.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.